# Different reference numbering per chapter

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a LaTeX document broken up into chapter, sections, and subsections. The theorems are numbered according to the section.

If I reference a theorem from a particular chapter in the same chapter, I would like it to show up as

> Theorem section.#.

If I reference the theorem from a different chapter, I want it to show up as

> Theorem chapter.section.#.

How can I do this?

Edit:

I know very little about LaTeX. This is a portion of what appears at the beginning.

```
\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}

\newtheorem*{theorem-non}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[subsection]{Acknowledgement}

\newtheorem{algorithm}[subsection]{Algorithm}

\newtheorem{axiom}[subsection]{Axiom}

\newtheorem{case}[subsection]{Case}

\newtheorem{claim}[subsection]{Claim}

\newtheorem{conclusion}[subsection]{Conclusion}

\newtheorem{condition}[subsection]{Condition}

\newtheorem{conjecture}[subsection]{Conjecture}

\newtheorem{corollary}[subsection]{Corollary}
```

I hope this helps. If something more specific/different is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Please post a Minimum Working Example i.e. code people can compile to reproduce the problem. This should show what you've tried. At the very least it should provide enough code for people to try out solutions. Right now we have no idea what class or packages you are using which might be affecting the existing formatting of references.

Comment: Your example is not working! See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that and please edit your code accoringly.